# Write simple ES avg aggregation in golang

Tags: go, elasticsearch

I've been trying to write a simple ES avg aggregation in GO but even though this sound I am not sure how to parse the result:

```
     ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), defaultTimeout)
     defer cancel()
     query := elastic.NewAvgAggregation().Field("Assignment.HomeworkSize")
     ss := elastic.NewSearchSource().Query(query)
     searchResult, err := c.ES.Search().Index(StudentIndex).SearchSource(ss).Do(ctx)
     if err != nil {
         return 0, err
     }
     // Parse Results
     aggs := searchResult.Aggregations
```

But I am not sure how to parse `searchResult` to get the result of this aggregation. Basically I want to parse a bulk of documents representing a Student and get the average size of a homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using http to get to elastic usually. So I return result as map and it's possible to check with debugger what is your result and work from there.

```
var resp map[string]interface{}
err := c.handleRequest(http.MethodGet, tag, req, &resp)
```

where tag is your index, req - request you are doing to elastic, and response is response

inside handler it looks like this:

`req, err := http.NewRequest(method, c.endpoint+tag, bytes.NewReader(jsonBody))`

where jsonBody is req you passed to handler
everything else is usual way to send http with go

one more thing to keep in mind is handling types(type assertions) in resulting map like so:

```
    for index, hit := range resp["hits"].(map[string]interface{})["hits"].([]interface{}) {

        Source := hit.(map[string]interface{})["_source"].(map[string]interface{})

        items[index] = someType{
            SomeField: Source["app_name"].(string),
        }
    }
```